# Auto-sync JS environment with LocalStorage or IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webkit, node-webkit

I am developing an application using nw.js. I'd like to sync the local environment (all JSON objects, arrays, etc) with the back-end so that the state can be resumed if the browser is closed and resumed re-opened. Ideally, I'd like to bind objects so that I don't have to manually and periodically write to local storage. Is there a library that does this for me?

I am agnostic about the back-end model as long as it can handle JSON objects/arrays. (I know LocalStorage is only key-value, though there solutions to this such as [StoreDB](https://github.com/djyde/StoreDB).)

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for specifically. You could write the state data to the local filesystem with node and just read that file when the app is launched.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of synching/binding. I'd like to bind objects to localstorage in the same was angular/knockout/etc bind the view to a model.